# Google maps info window open() panTo edge of map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, window, google-maps-api-3

i have these two lines

```
map.panTo(respectiveMarker.getPosition());//Center in map the respective marker
infoWindow.open(map, respectiveMarker);
```

When infoWindow.open is executed the map pans to the edge.
If i remove this line the map pans to the marker as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the [v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) you could simply prevent the `infoWindow` from shifting the map with the [`disableAutoPan`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions) option.

Complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps disableAutoPan Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 

   <div id="map" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.44, -122.14);
   var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'Test',
      disableAutoPan: true
   });

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Test Marker'
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: disableAutoPan]

There is no equivalent to the `disableAutoPan` in the [v2 API's](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html) [`GInfoWindowOptions`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GInfoWindowOptions), and I am not aware of any workarounds for this.

Comment: Thank you.It's a nice workaround.The info window also resizes(it's going smaller) so i think i do some mistakes here.It was working 2 days ago...